# how to display TMS layer in Open Layers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver, tms

I want to display tms layer in ol3.

```
  var layer = 'india:Indian_gdp_119';
  var projection_epsg_no = '4326';
  var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.transform([77.39907,28.58920], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom:2    }),
    layers: [new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      style:simpleStyle,
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        tilePixelRatio:1  ,
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf' }) })]});
```

In geoserver and ol3  pbf format is not working,getting same error in geoserver and ol3.
Error::

```
 http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/india:Indian_gdp_119@EPSG%3A4326@pbf/2/1/1.pbf 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there any mistake in this code.Thanks

Comment: GeoServer is usually on port 8080 which is not in your URL

Comment: I used proxy URL.

Comment: does that url work in a browser?

Comment: No, in browser also same error,only the pbf tms layers are display from tile layer.

Comment: check the GeoServer log to see what the error is? I assume you have added the correct vector-tiles plugin

Comment: ya,other all formats are working like Geojson,Topojson. Only mapbox vector(Pbf) is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166882/discussion-between-seema-barate-and-ian-turton).

Comment: Thanks lan Turton my Code working.

Comment: Please post the answer to this question as chat url isn't working

Comment: Hi Loveen this is working link::https://codepen.io/seema30fresher/pen/zLqVax on local machine please try it,Thanks.